# javax.jcr.RepositoryException: Unable to auto-create value for /e0a02fd0-d328-48f7-8874-685c591afe9a/jcr:createdBy

Tags: java, jcr

Soy nuevo en Jackrabbit Oak, estoy intentando crear nodos para almacenar ficheros (pdf, word, excel, etc). Cuando trato de crear el nodo especificando un tipo se lanzan excepciones similares a esta. **javax.jcr.RepositoryException: Unable to auto-create value for /e0a02fd0-d328-48f7-8874-685c591afe9a/jcr:createdBy**. No tengo idea de que pude ser, que esta mal, en la documentacion lo he visto asi. 
Ejemplo del code:
[image: Creacion del nodo para almacenar archivos]

Comment: Hola Rolando, que te parece si eliminas el "throws RepositoryException" y muestras que error surge y en que linea de codigo.

Comment: Gracias, pero ya solucioné el problema. Era la manera en la que creaba el repositorio.

Comment: Excellent!, sería buena idea agregaras tu solución para ayudar a otros desarrolladores.